# Auto scrolling to top of page by focusing on text field in mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, scroll

I am creating a HTML page where I have two text fields, one is at the top of page and the other is at the bottom. If I focus on second text field then my browser should auto scroll to the top side.

What should I do to achieve this? I am using Mozilla Firefox

This may be possible by auto scrolling, but how can I implement it?

Is there any other way to achieve this using HTML or Javascript or jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, but if I understand correctly you can try this:

Your first input should have an ID:

`<input id="top" type="text">`

And your second input should look like this:

`<input type="text" onclick="window.location.href = '#top'; return false;" >`

Hope that helps!

Comment: my question is,i have lot of text field in my form.ok.when i go to the bottom of my page through TAB button,that time my text field which is at bottom not seen clearly.i wanted that text field shold have to see clearly like middle or some thing top side.that set